# Xamarin Forms Refresh Layout after Observable Collection changes

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a though time trying to "refresh" one of the views where I'm using a [WrapLayout](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13/Controls/WrapLayout.cs). Even though I change the items inside the ObservableCollection the page does not show the changes made.

Code below (some obfuscation needed due to confidentiality issues but I think the most important part is all there). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

ItemCardsViewModel.cs

```
// INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on BaseViewModel
public class ItemCardsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public ICommand RefreshCardsCommand { get; private set; }
    public Action OnItemsChanged { get; internal set; }

    public ItemCardsViewModel()
    {
        (...)
        this.RefreshCardsCommand = new Command(RefreshCards);
    }

    private void RefreshCards(object x)
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(
            this.Items.Select(x =>
            {
                x.IsVisible = false;
                return x;
            }));

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Items));

        if (this.OnItemsChanged != null)
            OnItemsChanged();
    }

    (...)
}
```

ItemCards.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ItemCards : ContentPage
{
    ItemCardsViewModel ViewModel => ((ItemCardsViewModel)this.BindingContext);

    public ItemCards()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (var item in ViewModel.Items)
        {
            var cell = new ItemView { BindingContext = item };
            CardsLayout.Children.Add(cell);
        }
        ViewModel.OnItemsChanged += CardsLayout.ForceLayout;
    }
}
```

ItemCards.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" (...)>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            (...)
            <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,5,0,5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                <ScrollView.Content>
                    <local:WrapLayout x:Name="CardsLayout" Spacing="5" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                </ScrollView.Content>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention but I'm using Prism so the ViewModel is automatically wired up to the view.

EDIT 2: Just a quick update on this one... The issue persists even if I don't create a new Instance of the ObservableCollection on the RefreshCards method but rather loop through the records and set the IsVisible property one by one. Also tried to add a new ItemViewModel to the collection. Always the same result, no changes are shown on the page.

Comment: in RefreshCards, you are creating a new instance of your collection.  This will break any binding made to the previous instance of that collection

Comment: Hi @Jason thanks for the comment but I have exactly the same issue even if I loop through the records and make the change to the IsVisible property one by one.

Comment: Clear the observable collection items and the new ones to the existing collection.  Like @Jason said it will break the binding.

Comment: Does ItemViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: On which platform do you have this problem? Android, IOS, UWP?

Comment: Hi @jason, no. Only the ItemCardsViewModel is implementing it through the base view model but I can try to implement it also on the item view model too

Comment: Hi @hugorgor, it's happening at least in Android and UWP.

Comment: Try to surround your wraplayout with a stacklayout (vertical alignment) or maybe inside your wraplayout.  Playing with stacklayout can solve problems (I already had the problem and it was adviced by a MSFT dev)

Comment: Hi @Jason, even with the implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged on the ItemViewModel, result is the same.